# How to update latent discrete variables in MCMC?

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, latent-variable

Most of the discussion on Bayesian model with latent variables that I've seen fall into two classes:

- continuous latent variable underlying the observed discrete outcome (e.g. probit model ([Albert and Chib 1993](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2290350))
- discrete latent variable in a hierarchical / finite mixture model

I'm facing a model with discrete latent variable that is not hierarchical. I hope to get help situating this kind of model. Specifically, I'm modeling the two sided matching process between employers and employees. Both sides choose their best option among what's available to them. The set of what's available is called the opportunity set, which is a ($n_{employers} \times n_{employees}$) matrix of 0 and 1. It is therefore discrete.

This opportunity set is also latent because we only observe the final employee-employer match, not the full set of offers.

1) What's the name of this kind of model where a variable is latent and discrete? Textbook references would be great.

2) I'm especially interested in how one may update such a variable in a Metropolis-Hastings MCMC where the discreteness makes it unclear what proposal distribution I can use and how to tune its step size?

3) Could this model be coded in Stan and Hamilton MC, which requires the gradient and does not seem to work with discrete variable?

Comment: 1. I am not sure there is a specific name for model with discrete latent variables. For instance, mixtures are a case of discrete latent variables. 2. If anything, discreteness should make it easier. You can simulate the latent variables given the observables and the parameters, then the parameters given the observables and the latent variables. 3. Hamilton MC does not directly work with discrete variables.

Comment: What proposal distribution (for the Metropolis MCMC) would I use for the discrete latent variable?

Comment: It all depends on the conditional of your latent variable(s) given the observables and the parameters. It may well be directly simulable if the number of possible values of the latent variable(s) is small enough. As eg in the case of mixtures.